# How to deal with "TypeError" due to input shape like (None, 1024, 1024, 4) while implementing your own pooling layer?

Tags: conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I have naively tried to implement my own pooling and unpooling functions such that the indices are retained while pooling to map the values to the indices while unpooling. Here is the code.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Layer
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
import keras.backend as K

class MaxPool2DWithIndices(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filter_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid', **kwargs):
        super(MaxPool2DWithIndices, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filter_size = filter_size
        self.strides = strides
        self.padding = padding

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        '''
        inputs: (n, H, W, d), ie batch of n inputs of size (H, W, d)
        '''
        print (inputs.shape)
        inputs_shape = inputs.shape #K.array(inputs.shape)
        pooled_H = (inputs_shape[1]-self.filter_size[0])//self.strides[0]+1
        pooled_W = (inputs_shape[2]-self.filter_size[1])//self.strides[1]+1
        #if type(inputs_shape[0]) is not int: inputs_shape[0] = 1
        mpooled = np.zeros((inputs_shape[0], pooled_H, pooled_W, inputs_shape[3]))
        indices = np.zeros((inputs_shape[0], pooled_H, pooled_W, inputs_shape[3]))
        for n in range(0, inputs_shape[0], 2): # for each example
            for i in range(0, inputs_shape[1], 2):
                for j in range(0, inputs_shape[2], 2):
                    for k in range(inputs_shape[3]):
                        mpooled[n, i//2, j//2, k] = np.max(inputs[n, i:i+2, j:j+2, k])
                        indices[n, i//2, j//2, k] = np.argmax(inputs[n, i:i+2, j:j+2, k])
        return [mpooled, indices]

class MaxUnPool2DWithIndices(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filter_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'):
        super(MaxUnPool2DWithIndices, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.indices = indices
        self.filter_size = filter_size
        self.strides = strides
        self.padding = padding

    def __call__(self, inputs, indices):
        '''
        inputs: (n, H, W, d), ie batch of n inputs of size (H, W, d)
        '''
        inputs_shape = inputs.shape #K.array(inputs.shape)
        unpooled_H = (inputs_shape[1]-1)*self.strides[0]+self.filter_size[0]
        unpooled_W = (inputs_shape[2]-1)*self.strides[1]+self.filter_size[1]
        #if type(inputs_shape[0]) is not int: inputs_shape[0] = 1
        max_unpooled = np.zeros((inputs_shape[0], unpooled_H, unpooled_W, inputs_shape[3]))
        for n in range(inputs_shape[0]): # for each example
            for i in range(0, unpooled_H, 2):
                for j in range(0, unpooled_W, 2):
                    for k in range(inputs_shape[2]):
                        if self.indices[n, i//2, j//2, k] == 0:
                            max_unpooled[n, i+0, j+0, k] = inputs[n, i//2, j//2, k]
                        elif self.indices[n, i//2, j//2, k] == 1:
                            max_unpooled[n, i+0, j+1, k] = inputs[n, i//2, j//2, k]
                        elif self.indices[n, i//2, j//2, k] == 2:
                            max_unpooled[n, i+1, j+0, k] = inputs[n, i//2, j//2, k]
                        else: # it is 3
                            max_unpooled[n, i+1, j+1, k] = inputs[n, i//2, j//2, k]
        return max_unpooled
```

Let the following model be an example to replicate the error:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(1024, 1024, 1))

encoded_out = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same")(input_layer)
encoded_out, indices1 = MaxPool2DWithIndices(filter_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid')(encoded_out)

decoded_out = MaxUnPool2DWithIndices(filter_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid')(encoded_out, indices1)
decoded_out = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same")(decoded_out)

model = Model(input_layer, decoded_out)
```

The above code outputs the following with the error:

```
(None, 1024, 1024, 4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-5a2cf359f3ac> in <module>
      2 
      3 encoded_out = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same")(input_layer)
----> 4 encoded_out, indices1 = MaxPool2DWithIndices(filter_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid')(encoded_out)
      5 
      6 decoded_out = MaxUnPool2DWithIndices(filter_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid')(encoded_out, indices1)

<ipython-input-76-8a54043c249e> in __call__(self, inputs)
     20         pooled_W = (inputs_shape[2]-self.filter_size[1])//self.strides[1]+1
     21         #if type(inputs_shape[0]) is not int: inputs_shape[0] = 1
---> 22         mpooled = np.zeros((inputs_shape[0], pooled_H, pooled_W, inputs_shape[3]))
     23         indices = np.zeros((inputs_shape[0], pooled_H, pooled_W, inputs_shape[3]))
     24         for n in range(0, inputs_shape[0], 2): # for each example

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is of course due to the batch size not being known beforehand. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__call__` functions required some if-else conditions to deal with cases like input.shape=(None, H, W, d) or input.shape=(None, None, None, d). Solved!